# Value for each checkbox in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know how I can set values for each checkboxs. For example: I have 2 checkboxes, and their values will be:

```
Checkbox One: 1
Checkbox two: 16
```

If I select Checkbox One + Two I'll update my input value for: 17. But If I uncheck checkbox two, the value will update to 1 and vice-versa.

I made this, months ago...But I lot when I format my computer, I already do something like in C#, but i need to do the same in Web.

I don't want a full source-code, I just want tips that how I can handle this.

Comment: "tips"? use jquery selectors and jquery events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set the value attribute of each checkbox to the value you want, use a jquery selector to get all the checked checkboxes, and use a $.each to sum the checked values.